# Vagrant Multiple VM's with Unique IP address on public_network using DHCP

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

**host machine:** Ubunutu Server 20.04

**Tools:**
Vagrant

**box/image being used**
custom ubuntu server image.

**Vagrantfile:**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :


$veh= 1
$vehCount = 2

$vehList ={}


while $veh<= $vehCount do
  $vehList["veh_#{$veh}"] = "525400" + Array.new(6){[*"A".."F", *"0".."9"].sample}.join
  $veh+=1
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  $vehList.each do |vehName, macADDR|
   
    config.vm.define vehName do |v|

      v.vm.box = "vehserver"
     
      v.vm.network "public_network", :mac => macADDR 
    end
  end
end
```

Goal: What I want to be able to do is launch multiple VM's that will each have a unique IP address that will allow them to communicate with each other, and allow other physical machines on the LAN to have access to them as well.

What's actually happening: Instead of each VM having its own IP address, all VM's are created with the same IP address.

**What I've tried:**

- Pulled the VM creation out of the loop. I thought it might have to do with the way the loop was working. But if I separate them out, still the same issue
- perhaps it was that they were using the same Vagrantfile. So I created a second directory and ran all the same settings on both Vagrantfiles and again. All VM's had the same IP address.
- I'm running a custom Box image, so I thought it was the image. So I pulled `ubuntu/trusty64` down from the vagrant repo, and ran tested it against a single or multiple file build. and again all IP addresses were the same
- the first solution I found had to do with making sure the MAC addresses were different. I was able to do that with no issues. As you can see from the above Vagrantfile, I'm generating a unique MAC for each VM. However, this changed nothing.
- make sure VB is using a bridged adapter and not a host-only adapter. I've verified that the adapter I'm using, "eno1" is in fact a bridged adapter. I used vboxmanage list bridgedifs to list all bridge adapters.
- manage default router. so at the bottom of the page on [this link](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network) they talk about utilizing the DHCP on a public_nework using DHCP on the public network. the command appears to be deleting the default gateway. but I'm not sure exactly what its doing. In either case I attempted the instructions, and nothing came of it.
  Both VM's sees the default gateway for the LAN.
- and finally, I tried to do all of the above again, but deleting the .vagrant file first.

**What does work, but doesn't solve my issue.**
the one thing that works but does not solve my issue is if I use two different box images. For instance `ubuntu/trusty64` and my custom image, on two different file will create two different VM's with different IP addresses. While it works, it doesn't do me any good as I need the preconfigured custom box for my project.

How do I configure Vagrant to ask the DHCP server for unique IP addresses for both VM's?